# size in multidimensional array in c++

Tags: c++

this my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x,y, size;
    int array[][2] = {{1,2}, {5,6}, {13, 16}, {17, 69}, {100, 200}};
    for(x=0; x<5; x++){
        for(y=0; y<2; y++){

            cout<<array[x][y];
        }
        cout<<" ";
    }
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

the code work fine. But, when I replace line no.7 *`int array[][2]`* to *`int array[][1]`*, show error message like this :

```
64 E:\path\array_multi2.cpp:8 too many initializers for 'int [1]'
```

what the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

`int array[][1]` declares an array with only one element in its second dimension. You can't then initialize each of the elements in the first dimension with `{1,2}` or `{5,6}`, because that would require *two* elements.

You would, for example, be able to initialize it like so:

```
int array[][1] = {{1}, {2}, {3}};
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but how to know size of `array[]` and `array[2]` ?
so, the looping code can be wrote like this :

    `for(x=0; x<sizeofarray1; x++){
            for(y=0; y<sizeofarray2; y++){
    
                cout<<array[x][y];
            }
            cout<<" ";
        }`

Comment: @RieqyNS13 I don't understand your question. If you make it `int array[][1]`, then your `for` loop should probably just look like this: `for (x = 0; x < sizeofarray1; x++) { cout << array[x][0] << " "; }`. There's no point looping over the second dimension if there's only one element in it

Comment: if I replace line no.7 to `int array[][3] = {{1,2, 3}, {5,6}, {13, 16}, {17, 69}, {100, 200}};`
the code will show output :
`151 2 3
5 6 0
13 16 0
17 69 0
100 200 0`

the code should result output like this :
`1 2 3
5 6
13 16
17 69
100 200`
please help

Comment: @RieqyNS13 That's because your second dimension of the array has 3 elements. You are only initializing two of them with `{5, 6}` so the third element is set to 0. The same with `{13, 16}` and so on. Only in the first case did you actually initialize all three elements with `{1, 2, 3}`.